# actionbar item clicks are not detected when mediaplayer is playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making a mediaplayer with a custom UI. The player plays a hls video. I've added the support Action Bar to the Activity. The clicks on the items are registered before the video starts playing. but when `player.start()` is called, the controls are lost.
This is my layout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/videoSurface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@xml/progress"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
```

And my activity is this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kitkat_video_player);
    videoSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    controller = new VideoControllerView(this);
    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!subs.equals(""))file= getSubtitleFile(subs);
    // e.g. 3000 milliseconds
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(ConstantValues.name);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e("surface", "created");
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    player.setDataSource(this,hls_url);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
// End SurfaceHolder.Callback

// Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
    player.start();
}
```

and my menu inflators are

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_kitkat_video_player, menu);
    //subsbutton=menu.getItem(0);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sound:
            Log.e("sound","click");
            increaseVolume();
            break;
        case R.id.subtitles:
            subsboolean=!subsboolean;
            displaySubs();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The XML for the menu is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="br.com.panamon.herotakies.activity.KitkatVideoPlayer">
<item
    android:id="@+id/subtitles"
    android:icon="@drawable/subtitle"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Subs"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/sound"
    android:icon="@drawable/mr_ic_audio_vol"
    android:title="Volume"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="Chromecast"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

There are no logcat messages when i try clicking on the actionbar items. Also,sometimes the app freezes, and does not respond to any touch when its playing a video.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved the problem myself. the controller was overwriting the entire screen . fixed it by setting a height for the controller .